# awk choose a line with $1 present in a file and output with a changed field

Tags: awk

I've tried to use Awk to do the following:
I have a large txt file with first column the name of a gene and different values, essentially numeric, in each column.
Now I have a file with a list of genes (not all genes, just a subset) that I want to modify.

Initially I just removed lines using something I found in a forum

```sh
awk -F '\t' ' FILENAME=="gene_list" {arr[$1]; next}  # create an array without values 
        !($1 in arr)' gene_list original_file.txt > modified_file.txt
```

This worked great but now I need to keep all rows (in the same order) but modify these genes to do something like:

```sh
if ($1 in arr) {print $1, $2, $3-($4/10), $4}
else {print $0}
```

So you see, this time, if it is different (the gene is not in my list), I want to keep the whole line, otherwise I want to keep the whole line but modify the value in one column by a given number.

If you could include something so that the value remains an integer that would be great. I'll also have to replace by 0 if the value becomes negative. But this I know how to do , at least in a separate command.

Edit: minimal example:
list of genes in a txt file, one under the other:

```
ccl5
cxcr4
setx
```

File to modify: (I put comas as field separator here, but there should be tab to separate the fields)

```
ccl4,3,18000,50000
ccl5,4,400,5000
cxcr4,5,300,2500
apoe,4,100,90
setx,3,200,1903
```

Expected output: (I remove the 10th of 4th column when gene in first column matches a gene in my separate txt file, otherwise I keep the full line unchanged)

```
ccl4,3,18000,50000
ccl5,4,0,5000
cxcr4,5,50,2500
apoe,4,100,90
setx,3,10,1903
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I just modified my question and it should be easier to understand and test now.

Comment: The obvious adaptation gets _slightly_ different results for the third field but I guess that's why you have "something like" as a qualifier. Demo: https://ideone.com/mftzFy

Comment: Oh yes it works like what you did (I don t need to put an "if", I didn't have proper syntax), but now I need to get integer when there is a float generated by the calculation and a 0 when it's negative. While I see how to get 0 when <0 in 3rd column in a new line of code, I'm not sure how to get the integer, but I guess I could find that out. Could you tell me why you need a 1 before single quote in last line of your code? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spell out the arithmetic constraints.

The following is an attempt to articulate it in idiomatic Awk.

`if (something) { print }` can be rearticulated as just `something`. So just `1` (which is always true) is a common idiom for "print all lines (if you reach this point in the script before hitting `next`).

Rounding a floating-point number can be done with `sprintf("%1.0f", n)` which correctly rounds up if the fraction is bigger than 0.5 (`int(n)` would always round down).

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
  FILENAME=="gene_list" {arr[$1]; next}
  $1 in arr { x=sprintf("%1.0f", $3-($4/10));
    if (x<0) x=0; print $1, $2, x, $4; next }
  1' gene_list original_file.txt > modified_file.txt
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/oDjKhf

Comment: Just change `-F '\t'` to `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` as I'm sure the OP will want the same output as input separators.